# Excel: returning value in range based on 2 criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to work out the following.

I have the following columns:

[image: See image of worksheet]

What I am trying to do is to create a formula that will return the correct profit based on 2 values:

- Model name (M2, M3, M6)
- Type (Sedan, Hatchback)

So, let's say cell A3 = "M3", cell A4 = "Hatchback".
How do I create a formula that will return the value in cell F4, 16%?

What seems to break my lookup formulas is the fact that I have multiple identical values (Sedan, Hatchback).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(C3:H4,0,MATCH(A3,C2:H2,0)+1),MATCH(A4,INDEX(C3:H4,0,MATCH(A3,C2:H2,0)),0))
```